# Laravel 8 Model not updating when using cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 8 with cviebrock sluggable, my models do not update when I made a change.

When I remove the use of sluggable from my models, they work! Showing that sluggable is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is a breaking change, which occurred on Laravel 8 for me.

**Solution**

The solution is to add the following code to each model for which you use sluggable on:

```
public function sluggableEvent(): string
{
    return SluggableObserver::SAVED;
}
```

One can find a reference to the breaking change on the cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable github page: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

**Slug no default value error, as a consequence of this change**

You may get an error that your slug field has no default value, when SAVING, that is because the model will be updated without the slug, which will be updated when the model is SAVED.

To solve this problem, you can set the slug field to nullable() in the migration file, or at the database level make the field nullable and set the default value to NULL.

**Observer event changes**

Previously, one could check for slug changes using EventObserver@updating. This no longer works.

Instead, one can register a model event for 'slugging' or 'slugged' in AppServiceProvider.php.

For example (I have a model for events called Event, whereby I change the slug if an event date or title is changed):

```
Event::registerModelEvent('slugged', static function($event) {

     // $event->slug (the new slug)
     // $event->getOriginal('slug') (the old slug)

}
```

Bare in mind, for a newly created DB row for a model, $event->getOriginal('slug') will be NULL.

The "slugging" event is fired just before the slug is generated.

The "slugged" event is fired just after a slug is generated.